# Why can't I execute such code in my Python shell?

Tags: python

Why am I not able to run the following lines in my shell?

```
>>> try:
...     x = int("a lot")
... except items["error"] as e:
...     # Same as except ValueError as e
...     print("Couldn't convert")
```

Error message:

```
>>> try: ... x=int("a lot") File "<stdin>", line 2 x=int("a lot")<&>
         ^ 
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: >>> try:
... x=int("a lot")
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    x=int("a lot")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Which shell are you trying to use?

Comment: don't add additional info or corrections as comments, edit your original post.

Comment: womm;  Can you show the error you are having?

Comment: Please see Santas answer below. It might be nice, if you coud edit your question to include the definition of the items variable ;-)

Comment: >>> items={}
>>> items["error"]=ValueError
>>> try:
... x=int("a lot")
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    x=int("a lot")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Are you using tabs or spaces to indent? Try the one you're not using.

Comment: @Muzab: Don't post code in comments.  **Edit** your post to include the additional code or error messages.

Comment: Wait, are you copying the "..." into the shell as well? That's just the shell's display, you don't enter those.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
>>> items = {}
>>> items["error"] = ValueError
>>> try:
...     x = int("a lot")
... except items["error"] as e:
...     print "Couldn't convert"
...
Couldn't convert
```

Comment: That's right. The indentation should be inserted (a tab in the body of try and except block) and of course a complete example with previously defined items var.

Comment: I have Python 2.6.1 on Mandriva Linux. Any of my 'if', 'while','try' statements wont execute in the shell. Thanks for the quick response (guys)

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. Should be:

```
>>> try:
...     x = int("a lot")
... except items["error"] as e:
...     print("Couldn't convert")
```

Comment: @ ondrej ... my indentation was copied wrongly..i think it has got something to do with my version of python or i must import some file. I have no idea.